# Load a model into Tensorflow serving container and use protobufs for communicating with it

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-serving

I know how to load models into the tensorflow serving container and communicate with it via http request but I am a little confused of how to use protobufs. What are the steps for using protobufs? Shall I just load a model into the container and use something like below:

```
from tensorflow_serving.apis import 

request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
request.model_spec.name = 'resnet'
request.model_spec.signature_name = 'serving_default'
```

Or after/before loading the model I have to do some extra steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the sample code for making an inferencing call to gRPC in Python:

[resnet_client_grpc.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/resnet_client_grpc.py)

In the same folder above, you will find example for calling the REST endpoint.

Comment: Thanks it helped. I thought I have to create a .proto file for the model but it was just loading the model. The strange thing is the grpc and proto is not that much faster than using rest api. I ran a test and I queried 1000 times for an image using these two methods and grpc did it in 70 sec while rest did it in 71 sec, is this normal or the difference should be more than this?

Comment: Just for everyone information, as I found out the grpc shows its advantages when we are working with huge data. My previous experiment was with a very small image but when I used an image 100 times bigger (4MB) I observed that grpc is around 30% faster.